# Diagbox: compiling error

Tags: diagbox

The version of Latex running on my Ubuntu operating system is the following:

[image]

I'm having the following error message:
[image]

when I compile alone the file where **line 587** is, the compilation runs with success.

Here is the header of that file I can run alone with success:

[image]

That file I can run alone, at line 560, not far from **line 587** has the following diagbox instruction:

[image]

But that file I can run alone with success is only a chapter of my document. It is when I run the document that links together all the chapters that I get the error

[image]

Here is the content of my latex header file, the file «enteteChapLatex.tex»; you can see there the **\usepackage{diagbox}** instruction:

```
\documentclass[PhD,english,francais]{../principal/ulthese}

  \ifxetex\else \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \fi

    \usepackage{amsmath}          % recommandé pour les mathématiques
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{makecell}

    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{pdflscape} %landscape
    \usepackage{geometry} % pour \newgeometry{1.95cm} :astuce pour supprimer la page vide inséré suite à l'utilisation de \landscape
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{amssymb} %Pour \blacksquare

    \usepackage{fourier} %pour tracer le tableau complexe du chapitre de validation
    \usepackage{tikz} %pour tracer les graphiques, le tableau complexe du chapitre de validation
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} %pour tracer le tableau complexe du chapitre de validation

    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{multicol}

    \usepackage{diagbox}

    %\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}


    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,tikzmark, babel} % pour la librairie usetikzlibrary: cette librairie permet de tracer le tableau complexe du chapitre de validation

    %\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %pour justifier (center, left, right) les images


  \hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=ULlinkcolor}

\begin{document}
```

\tableofcontents

I don't know why am I having that error? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a `MWE`so that we can start working.

Comment: As I explained, when I compile alone the file where the diagbox instruction is, the compilation works. But this file is called into another file, and when I compile the latter, I get the error. There are 3 different files involve into the compilation process. If I force anyway to put all 3 codes in one file, the error might not occurs again and I would just stay stack at the same place.

Comment: Hum. I think that you misunderstand what is meant by a `MWE`. It should compile. It should be minimal. Working on it might help you understand or even solve the problem.

Comment: On `MWE` see <http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. Package `\usepackage{diagbox}` was missing into the principal file, the one that links all the chapters together.